# Long desktop load time after gnome login (approx 30sec)

Tags: gnome, login-screen, 19.04

I am experiencing long desktop load time in ubuntu 19.04.
The computer boots up fast as before but it takes about 30 secs extra to load the desktop home screen after successfull user login.

I have tried figuring it out using commands-

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

But,it shows only the boot process. But the problem is after boot, I guess.
Can someone help me with how to solve this problem or atleasr where to look for the signs which are causing this?

Comment: What environment you’re. Do you have ldap/active directory integration? Other network services like kerberos.

Comment: I am using stock ubuntu environment and dont have any services you mentioned.